# Regarding stripping the commas, colons in the list of numbers

Tags: python, dictionary, strip

I have a list of numbers in a file after binning the values to the nearest integers by using the `dict`,and `Counter` functions...

```
from collections import Counter
count_numbers=dict(Counter([round(x) for x in list_numbers])
```

and the values i got are:-

```
{1.0: 4, 2.0: 1, 3.0: 6, 4.0: 2, 5.0: 2, 6.0: 2, 7.0: 1, 9.0: 2, 10.0: 2, 12.0: 2, 13.0: 1, 15.0: 2, 16.0: 1, 17.0: 1}
```

But how can i get it in this form..?
1.0  4 
2.0  1
3.0  6
4.0  2 
5.0  2 and so on... ie., i need to remove the colons and commas from the list of values.. 
How can i do tht..??

Comment: Just loop over the dict `.items()` and print the key and value for each item: `for key, val in count_numbers.items(): print(key, val, sep=" ")`.

Comment: If the object is a `dictionary`, then it must have `colons` and `commas`. If you want to get the `key` and `value` of the `dictionary`, then you can use `for key, val in count_numbers.items():`.

Answer (score 1):

You can format the output to look the way you want like this:

```
from collections import Counter 
count_numbers = dict(Counter([round(x) for x in list_numbers])
for key, value in count_numbers.items():
    print key, value,
    # in python 3 use
    # print('%s %s ' % (key, value), end='')
print
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if youre confusing what you got. That looks like a dictionary to me. If you used print() to print that, then all it did was print it in 'key: value' format.

Answer (score 0):

`count_numbers.keys()` will give you the keys of the dictionary 
i.e, 1.0,2.0... as a list similarly `count_numbers.values()` gives the values 4,1,6... in the same order just manipulate the lists to get the format you need

Answer (score 0):

## Output: 1.0 4 2.0 1 3.0 6 4.0 2 5.0 2

```
dict = {1.0: 4, 2.0: 1, 3.0: 6, 4.0: 2, 5.0: 2, 6.0: 2, 7.0: 1, 9.0: 2, 10.0: 2, 12.0: 2, 13.0: 1, 15.0: 2, 16.0: 1, 17.0: 1}

for k,v in dict.items():
    print k,v
```